# Horizontal scrollbar not working asp.net

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

The css for my scrollbar is as below:

```
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color: #555;
}
```

The changes are properly reflected in the vertical scrollbar but the horizontal scrollbar appears very different.

Does anyone know the reason why?

Comment: Remove the asp.net and c# tag. This has no relation with asp.net and c#

Comment: Make a fiddle of your code or a Snippet

Comment: But it is working fine. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dhckpL54/.

Comment: And this one with height: http://jsfiddle.net/dhckpL54/1/

Comment: No,it is not working int the fiddle also.Note,the horizontal scrollbar is thicker

Comment: That is why I set `height: 5px` in the next link.  http://jsfiddle.net/dhckpL54/1

Comment: Yes,it worked ! Please write that as an answer so that I can mark it correct.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dhckpL54/1/

**CSS:**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;    /*   <---- This was missing  */
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color: #555;
}
```